# 3D lines not rendering out of WebGL Globe (potential CSS conflict?)

Tags: javascript, css, three.js, splunk, webgl-globe

I am trying to add a [WebGL Globe visualization](http://www.chromeexperiments.com/globe) into a custom SaaS application (Splunk) and instead of getting lines out of the globe, I only see dots.

[image]

I suspect the application has its own CSS or something that is overriding and hiding or preventing the lines from coming out. But I have no idea where to start debugging and what "troublesome" CSS properties I should be looking for.

I'm not sure if this helps, but here are 2 screenshot of the CSS properties of the 2 elements: the `<div>` and the `<canvas>` that is inside the `<div>`:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/x7qqkhimkh34h8q/Screenshot%202014-09-26%2000.40.35.png?dl=0
https://www.dropbox.com/s/h79190dgf2k99w6/Screenshot%202014-09-26%2000.40.44.png?dl=0

My [sample JSON data](http://projects.cultureplex.ca/globe/poverty.json) is from [this tutorial](http://versae.blogs.cultureplex.ca/2012/05/14/creating-a-globe-of-data-revisited-for-programming-historian-second-edition/) and it is valid. I even tried a very simple dataset of

```
[['series1', [0, 0, 1]]]
```

and even that didn't work (there was just one dot).

Comment: Could you upload your code somewhere? It's difficult to see what's going on just from the screenshots...

Comment: @mrdoob I'm afraid the code won't make much sense since I edited to "import" it into Splunk using RequireJS. I kept the code as similar as possible to the original Chrome Experiment examples. Anyway here you go: https://github.com/hobbes3/splunk_globe (the JS files are https://github.com/hobbes3/splunk_globe/tree/master/appserver/static)

Comment: Where is the index.html?

Comment: Hmmm, maybe you can prepare a simpler test? Chances are you'll find what's wrong on when doing that.

Comment: Ya, I'll create try to reproduce the problem without Splunk. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

Your magnitudes in your JSON file are really small which leads to the dots not looking like lines. try increasing the magnitude to something closer to approximately 0.5 or so.